# Is it possible to combine alleffects or effect with rsm in R?

Tags: r

I tried a rsm with linear terms:

```
> rsm_test.2 <- rsm(Nu_2H_Mittel ~ FO(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x5, x6) , data=Nu_112_gr_7.5.coded )

>  plot(allEffects(rsm_test.2), ask=False)
```

but got the error message: (translation from German!)

> Error in in  plot(allEffects(rsm_test.2), ask = False) : 
>   Error with the evaluation of the Argument 'x' with  the method selection
>   for function 'plot': Error in lapply (X = X, FUN = FUN, ...) : Object 'x1' not found

**Example:**

```r
un<-c(9.315076, 21.831509, 12.159635, 14.106338, 29.992457, 25.009093, 28.183301, 16.406841)
g<-c(  0.2681000,  1.1049000,  1.2030000,  1.0515000,  0.4709000,0.5366000,  0.4205000,  1.3201000)
D<-c(  12.282000,  19.311000,  16.785000,  13.271000,   9.191000,  18.261000,   8.454000,  16.338000)
er<-c(  1285,  1793,  1763,  1232,  1848,  1832,  1618,  1490)
un_all<-data.frame(un,D,g,er)
un_all.coded  <- coded.data(un_all , x1~(D-12.5)/7.5, x2~(g-5.125)/4.875, x3~(er-1750)/550)
#works:
rsm_un_all_coded.1 <- rsm(un ~ FO(x1, x1*x1, x2, x2*x2, (x3+1.75)^0.2 )+ TWI(x1, x2, x3) , data=un_all.coded )
#errored
plot(allEffects(rsm_un_all_coded.1))
#doesn't work
rsm_un_all_coded.2 <- lm(un ~ x1+x1*x1+ x2+x2*x2+ (x3+1.75)^0.2 + x1*x2+ x1*x3+ x2*x3 , data=un_all.coded
```

Comment: Can you please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can better determine what the issue is?

Comment: It could be that the `FO` structure doesn't work with the effects package. You could try fitting the equivalent model with `lm`: `lm(Nu_2H_Mittel ~ x1 + x2 + ...)`

Comment: yes this might be with **FO**.Seems that **rsm()** uses **FO** but** lm()** not and **effect()** needs the structure of **lm()**. Beside I need to **use at least one non linear exponential term** *(see example, I have added)*. This even doesn't work with lm but with rsm. Maybe this is the firts point I have to work on?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:
The model can be generated via **lm()** instead of **rsm()** for this case. But the higehr order terms have to be written as **I(...)**. Then effct works:

```
lm.test <- lm(un ~ I(x1+x1^2)+ I(x2+x2^2)+ I(x3+x3^2) + x1*x2) 
plot(allEffects( lm.test ))
```

Mixed terms *(like x1*x2)* have to be added without the "I".. BUT: effect treats them as own  factors and not together with x1 or x2 respetively..